# 7.4v to 3.3v convert

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit

I want to run two component one is 6v and another is 3.7v. I have a 7.4v battery. How can I convert 7.4v to 6v and 3.7v. I see some tutorials. here use different process. (1) using two diode can get 5.8v and and using 5 diode in series can get 3.9v. (2) using Zener di0de can get desire voltage. (3) using voltage regulator ic (7805,1117 etc). I want to know Which will be best. and if any problem or limitation of these process

Comment: How much current does your load take and how much does it vary? Is cost or efficiency more important for your design? What's your expectation about cost (i.e. is a $1 solution okay, or do you need a $0.05 solution)? How much variation in supply voltage can your load accept?

Comment: output current need for 3.7v component 0.6A and for 6v component 0.3A

Comment: And the other questions?

Comment: price not fact. which will be batter service

Comment: You have something of a habit of asking questions on this sort of subject which are missing key information.  Please spend some time reading the guidelines on how this site is supposed to be used.  In your diode proposal you also seem to be *still* overlooking the fact that your battery cells are *not* actually 3.7 or 7.4 volts, even though this has been pointed out specifically to you in at least one of your earlier questions.

Comment: **U must Learn how to translate a problem into engineering specs.**  Voltage tolerance, Current range for input and outputs. If  specs can not be made., no one judge if it is acceptable (meets spec)

Answer (score 1):

The best choice depends on requirements you haven't shared.

If low cost is most important, you might use one of the diode based solutions. If spending more than $0.25 is acceptable, you should probably go ahead and use at least a linear regulator, rather than rely on diode drops.

If the supply voltages for your loads need to be set very accurately, or if the load currents vary dramatically (for example, they have a shutdown mode where they draw very little current), then you should prefer a regulated design over an unregulated one (just using diodes).

If efficiency (or battery life) is important, you should consider using a switching power supply rather than any of your proposed solutions.

If very low supply noise is important, you could prefer a linear regulator, or a switching regulator cascaded with a linear regulator.

Etc.

Comment: how use switching regulator? If I use one Zener diode rather than 5 diode for 3.7v. it will better?

Comment: Switching regulator: choose an appropriate chip or module, read its documents, add it to your design according to its documented usage and requirements. Zener diode vs Si diodes: You haven't said enough about your requirements and how you define "better" to answer the question. Since you said cost is not a factor I wouldn't generally recommend either one.

Comment: @CloudyAkash Look up a part and follow their application and design notes. No vendor is going to leave you in the dark about how to design it, unless it's a cheap part from China.

Comment: If I add a 4.1v Zener diode I will get 3.7v. But why needs to use ic or 5 diode?

Comment: How much can you allow the voltage to change? If your load has a very low-current mode, the zener diode might drop much less than its nominal zener voltage, leading to over-voltage on the load. Same thing for the 5 diode solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the current of the loads you can calculate the heat dissipated in a linear regulator or zener diode for a reference voltage.  You may need to heatsink, in which case an LDO in a TO220 or DPAK would be a good choice.  Also how long does it need to run for ? Choose an option thats reliable.

Daisy chaining diodes to give a voltage drop will take up more space, it will most likely drift more with temperature. And its not very elegant !

Edit - based on those currents listed of 0.6A and 0.3A i'd go with an LDO and a heatsink.

Comment: If I add a 4.1v Zener diode I get the 3.7v. but why I use ic or 5 diode?